Работа SSAS (Analysis Server) с удалённой базой PostgreSQL
Коллеги, такая проблема.
Я пытаюсь осознать и начать работать с OLAP-кубами средствами MS.
Ранее мой опыт сводился к применению Power BI, Power Pivot, Power Query, в чём я поднаторел.
Теперь у меня возникает сложная задача, к которой я пытаюсь системно подойти. Задача состоит в том, что есть необходимость анализировать множество данных, разложенных в разных таблицах на удалённых серверах. Безусловно, я бы мог затянуть всё это в Excel или Power BI, но не хочется хранить эту инфу локально в файлах и обновлять при подключениях. Тем более, что хочется экспериментировать с построениями и делать манипуляций. Так я обратил своё вниманием SSIS, SSAS, SSRS.
Я хочу подключиться к удалённым данных и на них, средствами DAX строить метрики и создавать OLAP-куб, к которому, в свою очередь, я буду подключаться Excel или BI и заниматься визуализацией (хотя, как  я понял? SSRS может сам строить отчёты).
Я настроил на ODBС connect и добавил в SSMS удалённую базу с таблицами. Но как теперь начать работать с ней с аналитикой - не могу подступиться.
SSIS, как я понял, направлен на "затягивание" данных на свой локальный сервер (или любой другой), но этот вариант мне не очень подходит, поскольку данных очень много. Как я могу начать работать с аналитикой не используя сервера MS, а применяя удаленное подключение к PostgreSQL
